# Word Macro for replacing text

Tags: vba, ms-word

I'm still getting my feet wet with VBA but can normally piece something together. This time though I think I may be aiming too high.

I have a project that involves about 300 Word docs that vary in length from 1 to 40 pages. Each of these have text that need to be changed to mergefields (e.g.  needs to be changed to {MERGEFIELD "SentDate"})

There are about 40-50 possible mergefields that can be used and I've created macros for them so that users can just insert them directly. So far we have been using Find/Replace with ^c in the replace box but not all of my users have the same technical proficiency and I was hoping to create a macro that would take any guess work out. This project is a tad on the larger side but similar projects occur frequently enough that

In a perfect world the user could highlight the text they wanted to replace throughout the document, run the macro and it would give them a list of mergefields/macros to choose from, then it would replace all instances of that text with the selected mergfield/macro.

In a truly perfect world it would also ask them if they wanted to perform the same action on any other documents.

Any guidance would be appreciated:

Is this even feasible?
Is there a better way that I'm not thinking of?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow :-) Please take a moment to read the guidelines for asking questions on this site in [help]. As it stands, your question is much too broad and invites personal opinion...

Comment: Yes, it's feasible. "Better way" is a matter of opinion and depends on what someone considers "better".